# Swap Strings within a line in Bash

Tags: regex, macos, bash, shell, sed

I'm parsing a document with a bash script and output different parts of it. At one point i need find and reformat text in the form of:

```
(foo)[X]
[Y]
(bar)[Z]
```

to something like:

```
X->foo
Y
Z->bar
```

Now, I'm able to grep the parts I want with RegEx, but I'm having trouble swapping the two elements in one line and handling the fact that the text in parentheses is optional. Is this even possible with a combination of sed and grep?

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -e 's/(\([^)]*\))\[\([^]]*\)]/\2->\1/' -e 's/\[\([^]]*\)]/\1/' file
```

This works for your given input example:

```
X->foo
Y
Z->bar
```

You might need to make the patterns more strict if you have more kinds of input to handle.

Comment: it really does. wow, seems like i still have a lot to learn about sed! could you maybe elaborate a little bit how you actually did the swapping with a simple substitute command? your code works and my problem is solved, but im having trouble completely understanding your code. thanks so much!

Comment: ok i think i got it,  but shouldnt you escape the last " ] " in each of your substitutes?

Comment: That's great you figured it! No need to escape the closing `]` when it is outside of a `[...]`. (If we needed to escape, my answer wouldn't work...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F '[][()]+' '{print (NF>3 ? $3 "->" $2 : $2)}' file
X->foo
Y
Z->bar
```

Comment: your answer is the easiest to underand and yet i think ill stick with the sed solution. thank you for your time, i should really make myself familiar with awk.

Comment: `sed`  cannot do it in one pass as you can see from 2 substitute commands in janos's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it in `bash` itself, although it's not pretty.

```
# Three capture groups:
#  1. The optional paranthesized text
#  2. The contents of the parentheses
#  3. The contents of the square brackets
regex="(\((.*)\))?\[(.*)\]"

while IFS= read -r str; do
  [[ "$str" =~ $regex ]]

  # If the 2nd array element is not empty, print -> followed by the
  # non-empty value.
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]:+->${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but i think i prefer the sed and awk methods :)